# XCode menu item missing

Tags: xcode

I am busy installing OData for Objective-C, and in the instructions it says the following:

On the XCode menu bar, click “Project” / “Edit Project Settings”.

Only problem is that there is no "Project" Menu item in the xcode environment that I have.  I am using version 4.2.1

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Project" menu item does not exist in XCode 4. Instead, you select the topmost item in the left-hand drawer (the "Project Navigator"). Make sure you select your project, and not any of the targets. An image of this can be seen [here](http://theruprect.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/adhocdistributionscreens1.png).

Comment: The new organization feels more integrated once you get comfortable with it :) If my answer helped you, I would be glad if you could accept it so that anyone else who stumbles upon this question knows which answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try File | Project Settings instead

Do you see the Help menu item? The first field is a search field. This has the nice ability to search menu items. type `settings` in there and it will show you the menu item is.